# Button won't work in container view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a container view, and in the window it created I added a button. The button is visible, but when I click it there's no clicking animation.

Furthermore, I created an action using it, but it doesn't call it at all.

Here are some screen shots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have the button State: "Enabled"?

Comment: I didn't need to do that til now.. how do I do that ?

Comment: Just found it. Yes, it's enabled

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you perform any long task in main thread
2. check if the container view and the button userInteraction property is true and Enabled is true
3. select the viewcontroller from storyboard and make sure custom class ProductsView is assigned to it

Comment: 1) There're no tasks in main thread actually. The application doesn't do much atm :) When I moved the button to a different ViewController, the click animation worked.

Comment: 2) How do I do that ?

Comment: Just found it out - yes, button is enabled

Comment: 3) Look at the third picture :)

Comment: in attributes inspector search for userInteraction and enable it

Comment: I didn't find "UserInteraction", but I did find "State", and under it it's checked as "Enabled". What am I missing ?

Comment: I just found it, and user interaction was enabled.

Comment: I'm not able to upload it, but maybe TeamViewer will work ?

Comment: copy app and remove any private content any upload either in github or gitlab , currently teamViews not setuped with me